# What's the maximum amount of data I can store in a SQL Server Row?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Server as a backend database to an application. I would like to use one table in the database to store the HTML contents of a web page plus maybe ten other fields such as heading, name, and description in the one row.

Are there restrictions on the amount of data that I can store in a column and in a row? Also what is the best data type for the column that stores the HTML data?

Are there any guidelines on how I can store large amounts of data and still have these retrieved quickly? In the past I was using Azure table storage that had a 1MB limit for each record. Now I am concerned that if I use SQL Server I will have a problem storing the data.

Answer (score 4):

According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj553018.aspx SQL Azure limit for a row is actually bigger than Azure Table - 2G.

Comment: Thanks. I notice it talks of off row storage so I am wondering about the performance compared with Table storage where everything is stored in the same row.